# Cordova-android issue with bitrise tool

Tags: android, cordova, bitrise, cordova-android

```
* What went wrong:
```

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
> /Users/vagrant/git/corber/cordova/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:55: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 1m 32s
  (node:3223) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /Users/vagrant/git/corber/cordova/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  Note: /Users/vagrant/git/corber/cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemCookieManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
> /Users/vagrant/git/corber/cordova/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:55: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

Comment: Upgrade cordova plugins.

Comment: These are the plugins which I've used -
branch-cordova-sdk 4.2.4 
cordova-ios-plugin-no-export-compliance 0.0.5 
cordova-plugin-fastclick 1.0.0
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 4.1.0
cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.3
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.5
pushwoosh-cordova-plugin 8.2.0